# redis-cluster best max-memory limit setting for 40GB total RAM for 48 nodes

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

we have some trouble with our redis cluster in k8s (48 pods 40GB total memory each , the max-memory setting is 30GB ) and during pick hour  it start evictions at 30GB and this seems to cause performance degradation for the application , please, advice if I can increase this max-memory limit to 35GB or it is not safe? What is the best setting or range for this max-memory limit for this cluster size and total memory ?